# cytoscape.js problems with autoungrabify or autolock?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using Cytoscape.js to create a web application. To enable users to add edges, I have integrated the Edgehandles extension. Two kinds of edges can be added: undirected and directed. To add directed edges, the user holds down the control or apple key. To add undirected edges, the space key is used. Adding directed edges works perfectly. However, when I add an undirected edge, the nodes cannot be moved anymore. `node.grabbable()` returns `false` for all nodes. While this seems to always return `true` before adding an undirected edge.

I am surprised since all I do to make an edge undirected is add a class (see `cy.on('add', 'edge', function (event) {` even listener). At no point do I explicitly modify `node.grabbable()`. I thus highly suspect this has to do with the autoungrabify, or autolock functionality of cytoscape.js. However, as you can see in the code, I set those to `false`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It seems like the even listeners are not working here. So, you probably have to download the files to reproduce the problem.

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  elements: [],
  autoungrabify: false,
  autolock: false,
  style: [{
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge.undirected',
      style: {
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'source-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ]
});

var layout = cy.layout({
  name: 'grid'
});
var eh = cy.edgehandles();

var nodeIdCounter = 0;

function addNode(nodeType, position) {
  var finalPosition = {
    x: Math.random() * 400 + 50,
    y: Math.random() * 400 + 50
  };
  cy.add({
    group: 'nodes',
    classes: nodeType,
    position: finalPosition
  });
}

var spaceKeyDown = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  // Check if the Command key was pressed
  if (event.key === 'Meta' || event.key === 'Control' || event.key === ' ') {
    eh.enableDrawMode();
  }
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    spaceKeyDown = true;
  }
});

// Listen for keyup event
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  // Check if the Command key was released
  if (event.key === 'Meta' || event.key === 'Control' || event.key === ' ') {
    eh.disableDrawMode();
  }
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    spaceKeyDown = false;
  }
});

cy.on('add', 'edge', function(event) {
  var edge = event.target;
  if (spaceKeyDown) {
    edge.addClass('undirected');
  } else {
    edge.addClass('directed');
  }
});

addNode('observed-variable');
addNode('observed-variable');
addNode('observed-variable');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.9/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles/master/cytoscape-edgehandles.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #cy {
      z-index: 1;
      width: 70%;
      height: 80vh;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem you're having with Cytoscape.js and the Edgehandles extension has to do with the nodes' ability to be grabbed once undirected edges have been added. Even though your code has autoungrabify and autolock set to false, introducing an undirected edge causes the nodes to become ungrabable.

You might attempt the following strategy to address this problem:

Add grabbable: true to the node style in your Cytoscape.js configuration

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  elements: [],
  autoungrabify: false,
  autolock: false,
  style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'grabbable': 'true'
      }
    },
    // Rest of your styles...
  ]
});
```

Instead of modifying the node classes to make the edges undirected, you can directly set the edge data property directed to false when adding the edge

```js
cy.on('add', 'edge', function(event) {
  var edge = event.target;
  if (spaceKeyDown) {
    edge.data('directed', false);
  } else {
    edge.data('directed', true);
  }
});
```

By doing this, you prevent yourself from changing the edges' edge class, which could affect the node grabbability behavior.

Please try this method to see if it fixes the problem of nodes becoming ungrabbable after adding undirected edges using the Edgehandles extension.

Comment: Please tell me if it worked for you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that did not help.

Comment: my knowledge on cytoscape seems to be outdated I guess, sorry that it did not work out

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: it was not @tchrist and I wont be having that talk with you again

Comment: @tchrist This comment looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that posting AI-generated output is officially BANNED on Stack Overflow. If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE. Please read: Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed